# Объясните, пожалуйста, часть кода паттерна Singletone (PHP), сам не разобрался

Tags: php, singleton, шаблоны-проектирования

уважаемые специалисты! Не могу понять код ниже. Может, у кого-то найдется минутка по строчке объяснить..? Возникают следующие вопросы: 1) Зачем в if ( empty(self::$instance) ) программа проверяет эту ссылку self::$instance на существование.. и разрешает действие только, если "empty". Зачем нужно вот это: self::$instance = new self() и вот это: return self::$instance?

```
<?php  class Singleton {
    private static $instance;  
    private function __construct() { /* ... @return Singleton */ } 
                 private function __clone() { /* ... @return Singleton */ }
     private function __wakeup()  { /* ... @return Singleton */ }
      **public static function getInstance() {
            ****if ( empty(self::$instance) ) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;****
    }
    public function doAction() { }  } /* Применение*/  Singleton::getInstance()->doAction();  ?>**
```

Comment: вы почитали, что такое Singleton ?

Comment: Да, он обеспечивает, что в основе архитектуры программы будет один класс..

Comment: один экземпляр класса! вот здесь он создается. никак по другому его не создать

Comment: Общую логику-то я понимаю.. но, вот, смотрите if ( empty(self::$instance) ) {
            self::$instance = new self();   empty проверяет пуста ли переменная, self можно заменить на название того класса, где все происходит, :: ссылка на метод..

Comment: $instance  хранит этот единственный экземпляр. Если пуст, создаем

Comment: Я отдельные элементы синтаксиса понимаю, а во что они складываются - нет.

Comment: self нельзя заменить на имя класса

Comment: Тогда я неправильно понял ключевое слово self..

Comment: То есть функция getInstance кладет экземпляр класса в ранее созданную пустую переменную?

Comment: Вы не с той стороны заходите, как мне кажется. Всё проще. singleton должен отдать единственный экземпляр класса. он его и отдает. а в блоке if проверяет его существование. если экземпляр еще не создан - создает его.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался благодаря пояснениям и сам тут кое-что нашел.. теперь все понятнее..